# X Server from Windows to Windows - is that possible at all?

Tags: x11, rdp, terminal-emulator

I'm wondering if that's possible to run X Server (e.g. mobaxterm, xming etc.) on Windows that would display applications that are running on remote Windows machine.

I know it's possible if it's running on remote Linux machine, but still wondering if that could be possible on windows-windows environment.

I need to open Windows remote applications on my local Windows machine. I know I can use VNC / radmin / RDP but the problem is that these solutions give ALL remote machine. I have to display only specific applications on my local Windows, just like I open xclock.

Please advice... THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

MobaXterm will allow you to display remote graphical applications that rely on the X11 protocol: Unix/Linux graphical applications are all designed to run over an X11 server, so they can be exported and displayed through MobaXterm X11 server.

Unfortunately, Windows applications are not designed to run over an X11 server, so using Xming or MobaXterm to display them from a remote computer will not work, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Look man you could set up cygwin/X server one machine and run X apps from another machine pointing at that one, but I think you're asking a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Some vnc servers do actually allow to expose single window instead of entire desktop (x11vnc does and probably realvnc/tightvnc servers).